# RedisHttpSession is creating different sessionIds for requests from the same browser

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpsession, spring-session, lettuce

So I'm basically using `RedisHttpSession` for session management. I've created this login API which stores the `Staff` object in the session when the login is successful. `request.getSession().setAttribute("staff", staff);` And in other APIs, I verify if a valid staff is logged in and if not I redirect them to the login page. `Staff staff = (Staff) request.getSession().getAttribute("staff");` Now when I tested this whole scenario with Postman, it worked as expected but, I staged it on the server, and `request.getSession().getId()` is different in each request.

The other thing that I noticed was that when I was sending requests from Postman, I saw cookies being stored but there were no cookies on the browser.

Why is the sessionId different in each request? How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Well the above code is about creating a RedisClient/Connection and your question is about the HttpSession - which is more to do with Spring, both unrelated. You should look at the code where you're handling HttpSession management per request/response basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpSession` was creating a new SessionId every time because the cookie wasn't being stored in the browser. And to handle that, I created a new `@Configuration`:

```java
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://sub.domain.com",
                                "https://sub2.domain.com")
                        .allowedHeaders("*").allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This will make the browser save cookies but this by itself is not enough for everything to work well. You'll have to modify your requests on the frontend as well. Add `withCredentials: true` to your request like:

```
    const httpOptions = {
      params: new HttpParams({ encoder: new CustomHttpUrlEncodingCodec() })
        .set('fileType', fileType.toString())
        .set('jobDetailsID', jobDetailsID),
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('ngsw-bypass', 'true'),
      withCredentials: true
    }
```

Or you can create a `HttpInterceptor` and handle all requests:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor { 

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: CustomInterceptor ,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```